# How do I delete an item from a ListView using a custom DataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a `ListView` with an `IEnumerable<MyDocument>` `DataSource` pulled from a method.

The code in `myDocsList_ItemCommand()` definitely runs, because the document is actually deleted. My problem is that the `ListView` still shows the (now deleted) document until the next page refresh, even though I have code to do `myDocsList.Items.Remove(dataItem)`.

The simplified .ascx is basically:

```
<asp:ListView id="myDocsList" runat="server" 
        OnItemDataBound="myDocsList_ItemDataBound" 
        OnItemDeleting="myDocsList_ItemDeleting" 
        OnItemCommand="myDocsList_ItemCommand">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <table>
            <asp:Placeholder id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
        </table>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr><td>
                <asp:LinkButton 
                    ID="delete" runat="server"
                    CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument="X"
                    OnClientClick="javascript:return confirm('...');">
                        Delete
                </asp:LinkButton>
        </td></tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

The simplified .ascx.cs is basically:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
}

protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        IEnumerable<MyDocument> docs = getDocuments();
        myDocsList.DataSource = docs;
        myDocsList.DataBind();
    }
}

/* so we have the ID of the document we're deleting later on */
protected void myDocsList_ItemDataBound(object sender, 
                                        ListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    var deleteButton = 
        (LinkButton) ((Control) e.Item).FindControl("delete");
    deleteButton.CommandArgument =
        ((MyDocument) e.Item.DataItem).id.ToString();
}

/* or we get "raised event ItemDeleting which wasn't handled" */
protected void myDocsList_ItemDeleting(Object sender, 
                                        ListViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
}

/* do something here? */
//protected void myDocsList_ItemDeleted(Object sender, 
//                                      ListViewDeletedEventArgs e)
//{
//}

protected void myDocsList_ItemCommand(object sender, 
                                        ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int docId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        deleteDocument(docId);
        ListViewDataItem dataItem = (ListViewDataItem) e.Item;
        myDocsList.Items.Remove(dataItem);
    }
}
```

I've been reading up on the ASP page lifecycle and a few related questions, but I'm reasonably inexperienced with ASP and a bit lost.

How do I get my ListView items to disappear on the PostBack instead of on the next page refresh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to rebound data to your `ListView` in `ItemCommand` event, you can change your coding style as below:

```
//Create a new method for databind
void BindData()
{
    IEnumerable<MyDocument> docs = getDocuments();
    myDocsList.DataSource = docs;
    myDocsList.DataBind();
}

//Call databind method in your prerender event
protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindData();
    }
}

//Again bind data after delete operation
protected void myDocsList_ItemCommand(object sender,
       ListViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "Delete")
    {
        int docId = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        deleteDocument(docId);
        BindData();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was just posting simillar answer :)

Comment: No, your posted code is not alike to my answer. at `ItemCommand` event you've only deleted an item from `ListView` and database, but didn't bound again! But I only have deleted an item from database and rebound data to `ListView`, this is working fine! Would you please review and try again? Thanks for your time.

Comment: I mean that I wanted to post same answer but you were faster than me nothing more.

Comment: Oh! Sorry for stopping you, I would appropriate your answer, however, I would be more glad to have a vote from you :), thanks for your time.

Comment: Still not working in my code, but I'm beginning to think that there's a bug in my getDocuments() method - my suspicion is that the CMS I'm using (Umbraco) is returning cached content until the next request, despite my telling it to refresh the cache. I'm just going to workaround it by Response.Redirect'ing to "url?deleted=true". Thanks for the help.